# Refactor Rails 3 views - move logic to <model>_helper

Tags: view, helper, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like move the following from my View into the model's associated helper:

```
<%= link_to_unless params[:aged]=='0', "0", jobs_path(:aged => '0', :sort=>params[:sort],:dir=>params[:dir],:fav=>params[:fav]) %> |
<%= link_to_unless params[:aged]=='30', "30", jobs_path(:aged => '30', :sort=>params[:sort],:dir=>params[:dir],:fav=>params[:fav]) %> |
<%= link_to_unless params[:aged]=='60', "60", jobs_path(:aged => '60', :sort=>params[:sort],:dir=>params[:dir],:fav=>params[:fav]) %> |
<%= link_to_unless params[:aged]=='90', "90", jobs_path(:aged => '90', :sort=>params[:sort],:dir=>params[:dir],:fav=>params[:fav]) %>
```

I've tried this, but it causes an UNEXPECTED IDENTIFIER error (clearly I need to concatenate the results of the link_to_unless to the '|'):

```
link_to_unless params[:aged]=='0', "0", users_path(:aged=>'0',:sort=>params[:sort],:dir=>params[:dir],:fav=>params[:fav]) |
link_to_unless params[:aged]=='30', "30", users_path(:aged=>'30',:sort=>params[:sort],:dir=>params[:dir],:fav=>params[:fav]) |
link_to_unless params[:aged]=='60', "60", users_path(:aged=>'60',:sort=>params[:sort],:dir=>params[:dir],:fav=>params[:fav]) |
link_to_unless params[:aged]=='90', "90", users_path(:aged=>'90',:sort=>params[:sort],:dir=>params[:dir],:fav=>params[:fav])
```

It seems that I need to insert the results these helper methods into the HTML stream, but I'm not certain of the best approach.

Now that Rails 3 includes all helpers all the time (helpers :all) is there a way to instruct a model's view to only use the helper associated with the model?  At this point, I'm adding the model's name into the name of the function--for example, 'jobs_sorted_column'.

** edit **

Refactored

jobs_helper:

```
  def posted_filter(bucket)

    link_to_unless params[:posted]==bucket, bucket, jobs_path(:posted =>bucket, :starting=>params[:starting],:sort=>params[:sort],:dir=>params[:dir])

  end
```

view:

```
[ <% ['0','30','60','90'].each do |bucket| %>
    <%= posted_filter(bucket) %> |
<% end %> ]
```

Issues:

- Resulting output looks like [ 0 | 30 | 60 | 90 | ].  is there a simple fix to remove the 4th '|'?
- It seems like there would be a more elegant way to pass the params to the route, including the one 'over-ridden' value (:posted=>bucket, in my example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it even better:

```
def posted_filters(*args)
  args.collect { |bucket|
    link_to_unless(params[:posted]==bucket, bucket, jobs_path(:posted =>bucket, :starting=>params[:starting],:sort=>params[:sort],:dir=>params[:dir]))
  }.join(' | ').html_safe
end
```

And in your view code:

```
[ <%= posted_filters(0, 30, 60, 90) %> ]
```

Comment: i like the approach, but when i add the code to the associated helper, the result is a text string that is escaped HTML, rather than links.  am i missing something?

Comment: nope.  still resembles [ <a href="/jobs?dir=ASC&amp;posted=0&amp;sort=starting">0</a> | ...

Comment: that worked, thanks.  any thoughts on how to pass the parameters in a DRYer way?  i need to over-ride the :posted parameter; the others can remain in their current state.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `collect` and `join`, something like:

```
<%= ['0','30','60','90'].collect{ |x| "#{posted_filter(x)}" }.join(' | ') %>
```

See: [Array #collect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-collect)